# Dropdown Menu Doesn't Stay in Place When Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, datetimepicker

I have a situation where a Datetime Picker Dropdown Menu does not stay in place when user scrolls. Previous attempts using .daterangepicker `{position: fixed !important;}` have been unsuccessful , which results in the Datetime Picker not correctly staying fixed in its place, and also results in the user losing the ability to see the entirety of the Datetime Picker Dropdown.

Is there a way to have both the Datetime Picker Menu stay fixed when scrolling and also allow the user to see the entirety of the Datetime Picker? This issue has been difficult to resolve and any assistance would be appreciated.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

$(function() {
 $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
  timePicker: true,
  startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
  endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
  locale: {
   format: 'M/DD hh:mm A'
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  z-index: -10000000000000;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #89f7fe 0%, #66a6ff 60%, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
  margin:auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0.5;
}

  .daterangepicker select {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <link href="css/couponsexample.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body id="page-top">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="card shadow mb-4">
            <div class="card-header py-3">
              <span style="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end; width:100%; padding:0;">
                <button class="buttonTest" id="myBtn">New Discount</button>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content" >
                    <form id="msform">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                      <fieldset>
                        <h2 class="fs-title">Time Period</h2>
                        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 4</h3>
                          <input type="text" name="datetimes" />
                      </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

  <script src="vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

  <script src="couponsjs.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a simplest code related your issue ?

Comment: Hello Ivan thanks for the reply-I simplified the code above a little more. Basically Iam having trouble when a user "scrolls" with the Datetime Picker, where it "scrolls" with the page instead of being fixed. Basically I would like to have it fixed when a user scrolls and also be able to see the entirety of the Datetime picker. I believe part of the problem is the Materialize library but I need that for other functions on my webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you meant, at least it's what I understood.

**Add this styling:**

```
.card {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.modal {
    display: none;
    z-index: -10000000000000;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(0%,-50%);
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

The `.modal` will now be centered by `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(0%,-50%);`

The `.card` will now stay a the top, you were possibly targeting the wrong selector.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion-unfortunately, that breaks the entire view. Is there a way to position the Datetimepicker to be fixed but also show the entirety of the DatetimePicker?

Answer (score -1):

Set in daterangepicker.js:

```
this.parentEl = $(element).parent().closest('div');
```

or set in daterangepicker function:

```
parentEl: $(element).parent().closest('div')
```

This will make calendar relative to parent div of input rather than body (which is default) and will scroll along with the input.

You may need few more css tweaks like position relative of the parent and overflow not hidden.